# syntax error with KeyError in python 3.2

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

I'm a beginner using python 3.2 and i have a book whos code is all in python 2.6. i wrote part of a program and keep getting:
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
Then python's IDLE highlights the comma after KeyError in my code:

```
from tank import Tank

tanks = { "a":Tank("Alice"), "b":Tank("Bob"), "c":Tank("Carol")}
alive_tanks = len(tanks)

while alive_tanks > 1:
    print
    for tank_name in sorted( tanks.keys() ):
        print (tank_name, tanks[tank_name])

    first = raw_input("Who fires? ").lower()
    second = raw_input("Who at? ").lower()

    try:
        first_tank = tanks[first]
        second_tank = tanks[second]
    except KeyError, name:
        print ("No such tank exists!", name)
        continue
```

Comment: the code isnt complete but i got this error and stopped coding

Comment: after writing your question, you should highlight the code and click the code button. That'll take care of making your cod readable. I've done it for you here.

Comment: Python 3 is somewhat different from Python 2, and you will run into problems like this as long as you use 3.2 with this 2.6 book. I recommend switching either the version or the book. Here is a PDF outlining the differences: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/imprint_downloads/informit/promotions/python/python2python3.pdf

Comment: And here is more than an outline: http://python3porting.com/differences.html ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of

```
except KeyError, name:
```

try

```
except KeyError as name:
```

Its a difference between Python 2.x and Python 3.x. The first form is no longer supported.